# Why doesn't $S^n$ embed into $R^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

It seems obviously true, but how does one actually show this? Or what tools does one use? I only know the basics of homotopy theory and homology.

Can I use invariance of domain somehow? If $S^n$ embeds, then so does a neighborhood of it in $R^{n+1}$?

Comment: The image would have to be both open and compact in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: By invariance of domain, the image would be open. The image already is compact thus closed, and you'd get a clopen subset of $\Bbb R^n$ of which there are only two, $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R^n$ itself. But the sphere is homeomorphic to neither.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Why does invariance of domain imply that the imagine of $S^n$ is open?

Comment: @Seth because an embedding of the sphere restricts to an embedding of $S^n\setminus\lbrace p\rbrace(\simeq \Bbb R^n)$ for any point $p$, and such a map is open by invariance of domain.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat thanks, so I guess any compact $n$-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is embedded as an open set then?

Comment: @Seth yes, from which it follows that there are no such embeddings.

Comment: @user8268 Are you sure that result doesn't use invariance of domain? How do you prove it?

Comment: @user54092 sorry, when I see 'embedding' I automatically understand 'smooth embedding'; for topological embeddings one needs invariance of domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Ted Shifrin's hint, one can actually show a stronger result via the invariance of domain theorem:

> If $M$ is a compact $n$-manifold and $N$ is a connected $n$-manifold, then an embedding $h : M \to N$ must be surjective, hence a homeomorphism.

This is corollary 2B.4 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. To prove it, note that $h(M)$ must be closed since $M$ is compact and $N$ Hausdorff. $h(M)$ is also open by the invariance of domain. Since $N$ is connected, it follows that $h(M) = N$.

---

Your question now follows since $S^n$ and $\Bbb R^n$ are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

The image of $S^n$ would have to be compact (as $S^n$ is compact) and open, but $\mathbb R^n$ is connected and not compact.